# Why does Lua report that lua_pushlstring is undefined?

Tags: c, lua, undefined-symbol

I managed to compile Lua 5.1.4 for Palm webOS and now I'm trying to write an extension to use webOS' services from Lua. However, when I try to load my library, Lua reports:

```
undefined symbol: lua_pushlstring
```

Here's my code:

```
#define LUA_LIB
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"

static int hellopalm(lua_State *L) {
    lua_pushliteral(L, "Hello, Palm!");
    return 1;
}

static const luaL_reg palmlib[] = {
    { "hellopalm", hellopalm },
    { NULL, NULL }
};

LUALIB_API int luaopen_palm(lua_State *L) {
    luaL_register(L, "palm", palmlib);
    return 1;
}
```

Here's my Makefile:

```
LUADIR= ../lua-5.1.4/lua-webos
CC= arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
CFLAGS= -O2 -Wall -shared -nostdlib -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=softfp
INCLUDES= -I$(LUADIR)/include
RM= rm -f

LIBNAME= palmlib.so
SOURCES= palmlib.c

default: $(LIBNAME)

clean:
    $(RM) $(LIBNAME)

$(LIBNAME): palmlib.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(SOURCES) -o $@
```

I know `lua_pushliteral` is just a macro that calls `lua_pushlstring`, so that's where the error is coming from. None of the `push_*` variants seem to work at all. I suspect something is wrong with my Makefile.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export the Lua API symbols when you build your Lua interpreter. In Linux, the flags for gcc are -Wl,-E; perhaps this works in your platform as well.

Comment: Just so we know: when building Lua, does `make linux` work out of the box in WebOS?