# Lua: Cant open shared library when lua is wrapped in C++

Tags: c++, lua, linker, g++, shared-libraries

EDIT: Nearly got the answer, I just dont completely understand it, see last paragraph.

I try to build a shared lua library and use it within a larger project. When calling the script which loads the shared library from shell everything works. However, when I wrap the script within another shell, I get a runtime error when loading the library. Dependent on the script it is just any call to a lua function from c (i.e. lua_pushnumber). Here is a minimal example.

totestlib.cpp:

```
extern "C" {
    #include "lua.h"
    #include "lualib.h"
    #include "lauxlib.h"
}
int init(lua_State *L) {
    lua_toboolean(L, -1);
    return 0;
}
static const struct luaL_Reg testlib[] = {
    {"init", init},
    {NULL, NULL}
};
extern "C"
int luaopen_libtotestlib(lua_State *L) {
    luaL_newlib(L, testlib);
    return 1;
}
```

Compiled with: `g++ -shared -fPIC -I./lua-5.4.4/src -L./lua-5.4.4/src totestlib.cpp -o libtotestlib.so`

testlib.lua (testing shared library):

```
testlib.lua
print("start")
testlib = require("libtotestlib")
print("done")
testlib.init(true)
print("called")
```

Calling the lua script using `./lua-5.4.4/src/lua testlib.lua` works. Everything is printed. Wrapping script in the following c++ code does not work:

call_testlib.cpp

```
extern "C" {
    #include <lua.h>
    #include <lauxlib.h>
    #include <lualib.h>
}
#include <unistd.h>
static lua_State *L;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    int tmp = luaL_loadfile(L, "testlib.lua");
    if(tmp != 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    tmp = lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
    if(tmp != 0) {
        printf("error pcall\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Compiled with `g++ call_testlib.cpp -o ./call_testlib -I./lua-5.4.4/src -L./lua-5.4.4/src -llua` it prints "error pcall". If I print the error message on the lua stack, I get:

```
string  error loading module 'libtotestlib' from file './libtotestlib.so':
    ./libtotestlib.so: undefined symbol: luaL_checkversion_
```

In this case the undefined symbol is luaL_checkversion_ (which I dont call myself), but with other scripts it is usually the first lua_... function that I call.

I have tried several things to fix this. For example, linking -llua when compiling the shared library, but this does not work (and should not be the problem as calling the script itself works). I also tried to load preload the library from c++ (as done in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140905/undefined-symbol-when-calling-from-lua)) instead of from lua, but I guess it does not really make a difference and I am getting the same error. I also uninstalled all lua versions from my path to make sure I always use the same version.

What is the difference between calling the script directly from shell and calling it inside a c function? Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: Nearly got the answer. When using `MYCFLAGS= -fPIC` when compiling lua I can link lua to the shared library. At least this one works, but does not seem like a good solution to me and does not really answer my question: Why can lua itself (from shell) somehow add these symbols to the library while the wrapped c version can not? Additionally, my program has lua once linked in the shared library and once in the compiled C++ project (not optimal imo).

Comment: The host program needs to expose the Lua API to shared libraries. On Linux, you need to build `call_testlib` with `-Wl,-E -ldl` to export the names in the Lua API to the shared library.

Comment: Also, don't link the Lua library to the shared library.

Comment: @lhf Thank you! Thats basically the answer I was looking for. Will take a look at what these flags actually mean. Compiling works now without linking lua to the shared library.

Comment: See also the last paragraph of this section: https://web.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/install.html#adding

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59468871/cannot-load-c-dynamic-library-with-c-program-compile-with-liblua-a-lua5-3 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107102/why-does-lua-report-that-lua-pushlstring-is-undefined/3107908#3107908